# Azure DevOps: Blazor Deployment fails in Pipeline Build

Tags: azure-devops, blazor-webassembly

I have a Blazor WASM Pipeline Release build that was running well until I upgraded to .NET5.
Lately I get the following error: `...\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly.ServiceWorkerAssetsManifest.targets(68,5): Error MSB4018: The "GenerateServiceWorkerAssetsManifest" task failed unexpectedly.` followed by `System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\a\1\s\ClientSide\BlazorProject\obj\Release\net5.0\service-worker-assets.js'.`

My `yaml`-file:

```
trigger:
- main

pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/BlazorProject.csproj'
  solutionSln: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    command: 'restore'
    restoreSolution: '$(solutionSln)'
    feedsToUse: 'select'
    noCache: true

- task: VSBuild@1
  inputs:
    solution: '$(solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)/WebClient.zip"'
    platform: '$(buildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(buildConfiguration)'
    clean: true
    createLogFile: true

- task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  inputs:
    ConnectionType: 'AzureRM'
    azureSubscription: 'censored'
    appType: 'webApp'
    WebAppName: 'nextGenClientTest'
    packageForLinux: '$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)/WebClient.zip'
```

So for some reason I think it cannot find the file `service-worker-assets.js`, but I don't know why.
For the ones wondering why the structure might be strange: I have a solution file that I use to restore nuget-packges and in this pipeline I just want to build a specific project `BlazorProject.csproj` (which was working fine until I upgraded to .NET5).

Anyone knows, what's suddenly up with `service-worker-assets.js`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Azure DevOps: Blazor Deployment fails in Pipeline Build

There is an issue about it:

[Blazor Service Worker Asset Manifest path construction bug](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/25959)

And this issue was moved to the Next sprint planning milestone for future evaluation / consideration. And aspnetcore team will evaluate the request when they are planning the work for the next milestone.

**Besides**, in order to ensure that you have upgraded your project correctly, please refer to the following documents for some more details:

[Update Blazor WebAssembly projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/31-to-50?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio#update-blazor-webassembly-projects)

Comment: So it's a bug I can do nothing about. Good to know, then I'll wait for a fix and not pursue the issue any longer. Thank you very much.